# How to populate Account object market field value on contact object market field?

Tags: apex

Hi Every,

hope all are good and safe.

I need a small help on Contact trigger beforeinsert()logic execution.

1.Contact object have one Market field
2.Account object also have one Market Field
3.I'm creating a new contact through Contact object, In contact object I have selected a account record in lookup field.
4.Based on Account market I'm trying to assigining the same market value to the Contact object.If the Account doesn't have market value
then I'm trying to assign the user's market value to the Contact object.

This is my Contact - BeforeInsert() existing logic.  Where should I add my logic here

### Actual BeforeInsert() logic existed

```
public static void beforeInsert(List<Contact> triggerNew) 
{
    //string accOwner; *not being used*
    List<AccountAndContactOwnerId__c> ownerids= AccountAndContactOwnerId__c.getall().values();
    Map<string, string> MarketUserIdMap=new Map<string,string>(); 
    boolean isUpdate = false;
    
     for(AccountAndContactOwnerId__c customvalues:ownerids){
        MarketUserIdMap.put(customvalues.Market__c,customvalues.OwnerId__c);
     }
    for(Contact con: triggerNew)
    { 
        if(MarketUserIdMap.containsKey(con.ZTS_EU_Market__c)&& MarketUserIdMap.containsKey(con.OwnerId)!=null)
        {
            con.OwnerId=MarketUserIdMap.get(con.ZTS_EU_Market__c);
            isUpdate = true;

        }
    }

    set<ID> setAcc = new set<Id>();
    for(Contact con: triggerNew){
        If(Con.AccountId != null){
            setAcc.add(con.AccountId);
        }
    }
    
    //Shefali  22nd Dec 2014 Added for populating the City Text field
    ZTS_Account_Utility.populateCity(triggerNew);

    List<Contact> lstCon = new List<Contact>();
    for(Contact con: triggerNew){

        if(Con.ZTS_EU_Market__c == null){
            lstCon.add(con);
        }
    }
    // update market
    ZTS_EU_UpdateMarket.Contact_updateMarket(lstCon);

}
```

### Logic I have written

```
    For(Contact con : trigger.new){
        if(con.Account.ZTS_EU_Market__c != null){
            
            con.ZTS_EU_Market__c = con.Account.ZTS_EU_Market__c;
            System.debug('Market:::'+con.ZTS_EU_Market__c);
            
        }else{
            
            Id userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
            String userMarket = [Select ZTS_EU_Market__c from User where Id = :userId][0].ZTS_EU_Market__c;
            con.ZTS_EU_Market__c = userMarket;  
            System.debug('Market--->>>'+con.ZTS_EU_Market__c);          
        }
    }
```

Kindly pleas suggest some ideas and help on this issue how to fix this one.

Thanks,
Raghu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you simply have to copy the field value from Account to Contact. There are multiple ways to do it. The simplest one is to create a formula field on the Contact which will get the value from parent Account like this:

```
IF(ISBLANK(Account.MarketField), Account.Owner.MarketField, Account.MarkeyField)
```

For some reason, if you want the field to be an editable field, you can use the trigger(Or Workflow or PB) as you are using above. As the parent fields are not available in the before insert trigger, you have to query them based on the parent IDs first. Simplest version of the code would be like:

```
map<Id, String> mapAccField = new map<Id, String>();
for(Contact c : Trigger.New){
   mapAccField.put(c.AccountId, '');
}
for(Account a: [SELECT marketField FROM Account WHERE ID IN: mapAccField.keySet()]){
   mapAccField.put(a.Id, a.marketField);
}
for(Contact c: Trigger.new){
   c.marketField = mapAccField.get(c.AccountId);
}
```

For user, you have to do almost similar code and then you have to check if the one of them is blank, apply other.